# How to save [x,y,z] coordinates of a kinect depth image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, kinect, depth

I have a depth image from kinect that was saved using the Image Acquisition Toolbox. Using imtool I can see the x and y coordinates and the depth value of each pixel. I know I can save the pixel information by right clicking and copying pixel info but is there anyway to save the x,y and z values in a matrix automatically when a pixel is clicked? I know I can use ginput to save x and y but how about the z (depth) value?

Comment: How is the depth image stored in MATLAB? is it just a 2D Matrix?

Comment: @m.s. I am saving the depth image as a .tiff or .png file which I then use in `imtool`. I can also read the depth image into a variable which is a matrix of depth values.